# Message not received when sent through send_message endpoint of Ejabberd Api if the receiver user was offline

Tags: java, android, smack, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

I am implementing chat app and I can't understand why when I use modulue **Send_message** of ejabberd the receiver does not see the message.

I mean :

- User B is offline and user A send a message using ejabberd api through https. **
- when user B gets online he sees nothing ***

I am using smack in client side and I implemented the listener for incoming messages. but I see no incoming packet with Message extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that problem.

This is how I tested it:

1. Install ejabberd 21.04, default configuration, start it
2. register accounts user1@localhost and user2@localhost
3. Send message using the shell (no need to setup API):

   ❯ ejabberdctl send_message chat user1@localhost user2@localhost somesubject somebody
4. Then login to account user2@localhost using a good desktop Jabber client, for example Gajim, Psi, Tkabber, ... After logging in, the client receives

```html
<message to='user2@localhost'
from='user1@localhost'
type='chat'
id='13012384106679348680'>
  <archived by='user2@localhost'
id='1621974627878891'
xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/>
  <stanza-id by='user2@localhost'
id='1621974627878891'
xmlns='urn:xmpp:sid:0'/>
  <delay from='localhost'
stamp='2021-05-25T20:30:27.879994Z'
xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'>Offline storage</delay>
  <body>somebody</body>
  <subject>somesubject</subject>
</message>
```

Things you must try:

- Your client must login, send presence with positive priority, in order to receive offline messages.
- Try using a Jabber client to receive the messages, maybe the problem is in your client.
- And also try using the ejabberdctl script. Maybe the problem is in your API call method.

Comment: it wad a logical error in the  algorithms I wrote to call the Api. thanks.